# Pdf reading from tab

Tags: android, selenium, pdf, appium

For example, I need to fetch path of downloaded file from a android Tab.
Means i need to download a PDF file in tab and need to read that file
I am working on appium mobile webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should sync android tab folder with our desktop at runtime